# Unknown response for all methods and commands in ruby-asterisk

Tags: ruby, rubygems, asterisk

Testing ruby-asterisk manager interface with ruby version 1.9.3p0 and gem 1.8.11, for all command and methods its printing the the same output.

Anyone faced similar problem.

**Code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'ruby-asterisk'

@ami = RubyAsterisk::AMI.new("192.168.1.5",5038)
@ami.login("admin","passs")

puts @ami.command("sip show peers")
```

**Output:**

```
#<RubyAsterisk::Response:0x000000016af710>
```

[Project URL](https://github.com/emilianodellacasa/ruby-asterisk/)

---

**Problem solved**. Didn’t check the readme `RESPONSE OBJECT` section.
It's working.

```
var = @ami.command(""sip show peers)
puts var.data
```

Answer (score 2):

You are putting the Instance of the `RubyAsterix`. I think after haveing a brief look at the project that most/all of the instance methods returns the instance it self. The reason for doing it that way is that it makes it very easy to chain multiplie actions which makes for a nice syntax/usage.

I think you should remove the `puts` and allow the gem to display what it wants to display.